# Subscribe to "GetValue" of a DependencyProperty

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `DependencyProperty` in my UserControl -

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnConfigDataProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("ColumnConfigData", typeof(string), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(OnColumnConfigChanged)));

public string ColumnConfigData
{
    get{ return (string)GetValue(ColumnConfigDataProperty);}
    set { SetValue(ColumnConfigDataProperty, value); }
}
```

When the client application (that uses my UserControl) tries to access the DependencyProperty, I want to update the DependencyProperty with a new value. I didn't get how to subscribe to `GetValue` of the DependencyProperty.

Comment: This is not how dependency properties are supposed to work. The getter of the CLR wrapper shouldn't do anything else than call GetValue. A dependency property getter should always return the same value, unless the setter (i.e. SetValue) is called, or the property is otherwise set, e.g. by a binding or an animation.

Comment: I agree with what Clemens said. This is not the purpose of dependency properties. You bind some property in the view to a dependency property in the code behind and you update that property bound to it to update the view. There is no use in changing it while trying to get the value. It doesn’t make sense.
Please read this article on [MSDN about dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: @IDisposable "You bind some property in the view to a dependency property in the code behind". This is also quite confusing. While the source property of a binding *can* be a dependency property, it doesn't *have to* be one. Also, dependency properties work well without bindings, so their general use can't be reduced to data binding.

Comment: I just said an example scenario.